# Map2_df and named arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr

This must be similar to what described here

https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/179

but I am banging my head against the wall.

Consider the snippet

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)



remove_short_words <- function(x, n){

mypattern <- paste("\\w{", n, ",}", sep="")

x2 <- paste(str_extract_all(x, mypattern)[[1]], collapse=' ')


}


shopping_list <- c("apples x4", "bag of flour", "bag of sugar", "milk x2")


dd<-map2(shopping_list, 4, function(x,y) remove_short_words(x,y))


ff<-map2_df(shopping_list, 4, function(x,y) remove_short_words(x,y))
```

map2 works like a charm, but map2_df throws an error

```
Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

Any idea about how to fix this?
Thanks!

#

I add what works for me. I use an auxiliary function which I plug into map

```
remove_short_words_aux <- function(x, n){

mypattern <- paste("\\w{", n, ",}", sep="")

x2 <- paste(str_extract_all(x, mypattern)[[1]], collapse=' ')


}



remove_short_words <- function(x,n){


res<-map(x, function(x) remove_short_words_aux(x,n)) %>%
    unlist %>%
    tibble::enframe(name = NULL)



}

> nn<-remove_short_words(shopping_list,5)
> nn
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value   
  <chr>   
1 "apples"
2 "flour" 
3 "sugar" 
4 ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I don't think you should use `map2` here since `n` is fixed and is not changing so using `map` would be appropriate.

```
library(tidyverse)

remove_short_words <- function(x, n){
  mypattern <- paste("\\w{", n, ",}", sep="")
  paste(str_extract_all(x, mypattern)[[1]], collapse=' ')
}

shopping_list <- c("apples x4", "bag of flour", "bag of sugar", "milk x2")
map(shopping_list, remove_short_words, 4)

#[[1]]
#[1] "apples"

#[[2]]
#[1] "flour"

#[[3]]
#[1] "sugar"

#[[4]]
#[1] "milk"
```

Note that the output is a list of characters and if you need to combine this to one column dataframe you have two options.

1. Use `map_chr` -

```
tibble(val = map_chr(shopping_list, remove_short_words, 4))

#   val   
#  <chr> 
#1 apples
#2 flour 
#3 sugar 
#4 milk
```

2. Or return a dataframe/tibble from the function and use `map_df` -

```
remove_short_words <- function(x, n){
  mypattern <- paste("\\w{", n, ",}", sep="")
  tibble(val = paste(str_extract_all(x, mypattern)[[1]], collapse=' '))
}

map_df(shopping_list, remove_short_words, 4)

#    val   
#  <chr> 
#1 apples
#2 flour 
#3 sugar 
#4 milk
```

---

Moreover, since `str_extract_all` is vectorised you can also write this as -

```
remove_short_words <- function(x, n){
  mypattern <- paste0("\\w{", n, ",}")
  sapply(str_extract_all(x, mypattern), paste, collapse=' ')
}

tibble(val = remove_short_words(shopping_list, 4))

#    val   
#  <chr> 
#1 apples
#2 flour 
#3 sugar 
#4 milk
```

Comment: Thanks! I had come up with something along your line, but your solution is neater. The last version of remove_short_words is a perfect replacement for what I had written myself, but it is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand what you are trying to do but if your `shopping_list` is named this error goes away:

```
shopping_list2 <- shopping_list %>% 
  set_names(., shopping_list)

map2_df(shopping_list2, 4, function(x,y) remove_short_words(x,y))
```

Note that you don't need `map2` and the additional anonymous function defintion if `n` is constant. Also, use `map_dfr` or `map_dfc` (or `map2_dfr` or `map2_dfc`) to specify if the data should be merged rowwise or columnwise.

```
map_dfr(shopping_list2, remove_short_words, n = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks and let me explain. I would like a function which, given a vector of strings, removes from each entry of that vector all the words which consists of less than 3 letters. The desired result is a column vector or a tibble (1 column only). The returned object should have the same length of the initial vector.